# Linking One Background Image to a Set of Daughter Pages on NING

Tags: jquery, html, css, ning

I'm still new at CSS, so please forgive me if this question sounds elementary (it is).  Long story short, I'm currently working on a Ning Social Network hub for my school, and sufficient to say having a premade, pre-canned setup isn't exactly ideal for true customization.  I have set a mother page to a background image, and I want all the links (all leading to different pages on the same network) on that mother page to also feature that background image.  I was able to use the CSS box on the mother page to feature that background image, but for the life of me I can't figure out a way to do the same thing to any of the daughter page links.  I've tried adding and changing their IDs, but it only leads to a div being added onto them, and not exactly a background change when you actually click on the link and go to that page.  This is not that complicated and I know I missed something basic.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's the body html code of my "mother page":

```
<p><span class="font-size-3" style="color: #000000;"><strong><strong>1. <a     href="http://pharmacypeertopeeradvising.ning.com/page/healtheast-st-john-s-hospital-2012-2013-reviews" target="_self" id="AcuteCareAPPE">HealthEast St.John's Hospital, Maplewood</a></strong></strong></span></p>

<p><span class="font-size-3" style="color: #000000;"><strong><strong>2. <a href="http://pharmacypeertopeeradvising.ning.com/page/fairview-university-of-minnesota-medical-center-minneapolis-2012-" target="_self" id="AcuteCareAPPE">Fairview UMMC, Minneapolis</a></strong></strong></span></p>

<p><span class="font-size-3" style="color: #000000;"><strong><strong>3. <a href="http://pharmacypeertopeeradvising.ning.com/page/park-nicollet-methodist-hospital-minneapolis-2012-2013-reviews" target="_self" id="AcuteCareAPPE">Park Nicollet Methodist Hospital, St. Louis Park</a></strong></strong></span></p>

<p><span class="font-size-3" style="color: #000000;"><strong>4. </strong></span><span class="font-size-3" style="color: #000000;"><strong><a href="http://pharmacypeertopeeradvising.ning.com/page/united-hospital-allina-2012-2013-reviews" target="_self" id="AcuteCareAPPE">Allina United Hospital, St. Paul</a></strong></span></p>

<p><span class="font-size-3" style="color: #000000;"><strong>5. <a href="http://pharmacypeertopeeradvising.ning.com/page/regions-hospital-level-1-trauma-center-st-paul" target="_self" id="AcuteCareAPPE" name="AcuteCareAPPE">HealthPartners Regions Hospital-Level 1 Trauma Center, St. Paul</a></strong></span></p>
```

And here's CSS code I've got. Because its the NING network, the CSS is placed onto a "box" on the bottom of the "mother page":

```
<style>

#AcuteCareAPPE{
background-image:url(http://www.acutecarecontinuum.com/Portals/0/IMG_3192_ver2.jpg);

background-position: -50px, +10px;

}

</style>
```

So you see that I'm trying to make the links to those 4 pages (all have same ID of AcuteCareAPPE) to have the same background, but my CSS code ends up returning a div of the background image surrounding those links instead.

Comment: It will be great if you can share the snippet of the code.

Comment: make a fiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!  Here's the body html code I have on the "mother page":

Comment: Here's the above code on top.  What should I do?